# Как вытащить int из double

Tags: android, java

Как вытащить int из double a = 2.0
Делаю так:

```
int b = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(a));
```

Ругается! Вечер уже начинаю потихоньку тупить, так что не ругайтесь за такой глупый вопрос!

Comment: int b = (int) a; 
не работает что-ли?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Душевное решение, но лучше так:

```
    double a = 2.0;
    int b = (int) a;
```

Comment: может (int) a ?

Comment: естественно)

Comment: Обращаю внимание, что дробная часть в этом случае будет просто обрезана. Убедитесь, что вам нужно ее не округлить, а обрезать.

Comment: Преобразовать с округлением можно так:
double a = 2.9;
a=Math.round(a);
int b=(int)a;